# How can I recover my data after installing 12.04 over Windows 7?

Tags: data-recovery

I was using Windows 7 and had 250GB hard disk which were divided in many drives.

I lost all the data on disk after installing Ubuntu.

Can I get my old data back?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to add how you were trying to install,USB, CD etc and at what stage you lost your data, after the installation finished? Also I'd add whether you had a dual-boot already set up and any other relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Recovering after a format, since you probably selected "remove windows and install ubuntu", should be able with: [Easeus Data Recovery Wizard](http://www.easeus.com/resource/unformat-software.htm)

Its possible, but you must not have written something to it:

> Actually, to unformat a disk is a highly technical task. If you
>   accidentally format your disk, data recovery is possible. The reason
>   is that a format only reset files system, it does not erase data on
>   the disk; but remember: don't partition it again, don't format again,
>   don't write files onto it and don't install Windows on it again. In
>   this way, you are possible to unformat your data. The result of
>   unformat disk mostly depends on following factors:
>
> 1. For FAT type file systems: file fragmentation is a major factor. Fragmented files are likely to emerge corrupted, and un-fragmented
>      files will be fine. The format process destroys a number of important
>      bookkeeping structures on a FAT type partition, the FAT (File
>      Allocation Table) and the root directory. The absence of these
>      structures makes recovery complicated.
> 2. For NTFS type file systems: fragmentation is of little consequence. The format process only re-initializes a part of the MFT and most of
>      the MFT remains intact. Using the information stored in the MFT, even
>      fragmented files can be recovered intact under the help of a unformat
>      software.

I would say, give it a shot, just run a windows live cd, like [Hirens ultimate boot disk](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd).
BTW, they had a linux version, but they dont distribute that anymore, I am sorry I have no linux way for fixing this